# mongodb install error on linux node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, database, mongodb, command-line

I'm trying to install MongoDB with node.js on linux. I installed it with command
`npm install mongodb --save` 
, I can find mongdb dependence in packages.json file but when I use commands mongod, mongodb or mongo I get error

```
bash: mongod: command not found
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is you are installing a node.js client for mongoDB but trying to launch a mongodb server in a shell.

In order to use `mongod` command you should install mongodb server itself.

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install mongoDB in Ubuntu.

Comment: thaks so much, you really helped me

Answer (score 1):

when you run `npm install mongodb --save`, you just install the drivers to connect mongodb and your application. 
You can download the mongodb server from the official site [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community)